# Spark toDF cannot resolve symbol after importing sqlContext implicits

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on writing some unit tests for my Scala Spark application
In order to do so I need to create different dataframes in my tests. So I wrote a very short DFsBuilder code that basically allows me to add new rows and eventually create the DF. The code is:

```
class DFsBuilder[T](private val sqlContext: SQLContext, private val columnNames: Array[String]) {
  var rows = new ListBuffer[T]()

  def add(row: T): DFsBuilder[T] = {
    rows += row
    this
  }

  def build() : DataFrame = {
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    rows.toList.toDF(columnNames:_*) // UPDATE: added :_* because it was accidently removed in the original question
  }
}
```

However the toDF method doesn't compile with a cannot resolve symbol toDF.

I wrote this builder code with generics since I need to create different kinds of DFs (different number of columns and different column types). The way I would like to use it is to define some certain case class in the unit test and use it for the builder

I know this issue somehow relates to the fact that I'm using generics (probably some kind of type erasure issue) but I can't quite put my finger on what the problem is exactly

And so my questions are:

- Can anyone show me where the problem is? And also hopefully how to fix it
- If this issue cannot be solved this way, could someone perhaps offer another elegant way to create dataframes? (I prefer not to pollute my unit tests with the creation code)

I obviously googled this issue first but only found examples where people forgot to import the sqlContext.implicits method or something about a case class out of scope which is probably not the same issue as I'm having

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the signatures of `toDF` and of `SQLImplicits.localSeqToDataFrameHolder` (which is the implicit function used) you'll be able to detect two issues:

1. Type `T` must be a subclass of `Product` (the superclass of all case classes, tuples...), and you must provide an implicit `TypeTag` for it. To fix this - change the declaration of your class to:

   ```
   class DFsBuilder[T <: Product : TypeTag](...) { ... }
   ```
2. The `columnNames` argument is not of type `Array`, it's a "repeated parameter" (like Java's "varargs", see section 4.6.2 [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)), so you have to convert the array into arguments:

   ```
   rows.toList.toDF(columnNames: _*)
   ```

With these two changes, your code compiles (and works).

Comment: Actually the columnName is used as you showed in the 2nd bullet I probably accidentally erased it or something. I apologize for that. The extends product and typetag does work! thanks a lot :)

Comment: Just adding that the TypeTag should be imported using: `import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag` since apparently Java has a TypeTag class as well